# how to open evey li with mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu and I want to open every li when I hover on it but my jquery code dont work well and I try with css but the whole of menu was opened.

```js
$("ul.sideBarMenuLinks li").mouseover(function() {
  $('this').each(function() {
    $(this).css(' margin-left', '0');
  });
});
```

```css
ul.sideBarMenuLinks li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin-left: -116px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sideBarMenuLinks">
  <li>
    <div><a class="sideBarMenuLink" href="#"><span class="image"><i class="icon-home"></i> </span> <span class="text">Home Page</span> </a></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div><a class="sideBarMenuLink" href="#"><span class="image"><i  class="icon-user"></i> </span> <span class="text">Register</span> </a></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It should be `$(this)`. Remove the quotes. Also, I don't think you need `each`

Comment: yes tnx but whole of my menu is opened.how I can open every li Separately?

Comment: Even after removing `each`? Just so you know, this can be done way more easily in CSS

Comment: No I didnot remove each ,I only remove the quotes.this ul is inside of div with left:0;

Comment: Check the answers. That should solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this

JS

```
$("ul.sideBarMenuLinks li").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css('margin-left','0');
});
```

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

**Only with css:**

```
ul.sideBarMenuLinks li:hover {
  Your code style...
}
```

```css
ul.sideBarMenuLinks li {
  margin-bottom:5px;
  transition:0.5s;
  margin-left:0px;

}

ul.sideBarMenuLinks li:hover {
  margin-left:100px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sideBarMenuLinks">  

  <li>
      <div><a class="sideBarMenuLink" href="#"  ><span class="image"><i class="icon-home"></i> </span> <span class="text">Home Page</span> </a></div>
  </li>

  <li>
      <div><a class="sideBarMenuLink" href="#"><span class="image"><i  class="icon-user"></i> </span> <span class="text">Register</span> </a></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to attach `mouseover()` event to every `li` and then add `css()` to it.

```js
$("ul.sideBarMenuLinks li").mouseover(function () {   
    $(this).css('margin-left', '0');
});
```

```css
ul.sideBarMenuLinks li{
    margin-bottom:5px;
    transition:0.5s;
     margin-left:116px;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sideBarMenuLinks">      
  <li>
   <div>
      <a class="sideBarMenuLink" href="#">
      <span class="image">
          <i class="icon-home"></i> 
      </span> 
      <span class="text">Home Page</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>  
  <li>
   <div>
        <a class="sideBarMenuLink" href="#">
          <span class="image">
            <i  class="icon-user"></i> 
          </span> 
          <span class="text">Register</span> 
        </a>
     </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$("ul.sideBarMenuLinks li").mouseover(function () {   

                        $(this).css(' margin-left', '0');

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `hover` to chain your `mouseover` and `mouseout` event

```
$('.sideBarMenuLinks').hover(function(){
        //mouse over code here
         $(this).css('margin-left', '0');
    },function(){
        // mouse out code here
         $(this).css('margin-left', '-116px');
    })
```